# Get Request Working fine with Postman but not with PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, instagram-api

I have simple GET request on postman and it does working fine
https://www.instagram.com/p/CVhuRABqnAI/?__a=1&__d=dis

When Im using PHP CURL its did not respond me with Json data rather showing logo

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT   => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0",
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.instagram.com/p/CVhuRABqnAI/?__a=1&__d=dis",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($error) {
    echo "cURL Error:" . $error;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

Can some one else me with this?

Comment: Did you use Postman's code-generating feature to generate this from the successful postman request config?

Comment: yes I did try it still the same

Answer (score 0):

Finally I might know what to do as I just faced this problem.

Usually, there is just some kind of difference in between postman and curl. Or there is "something" else, because my solution was just to not send any headers at all...